# SQL Server 2012 and DBM

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, high-availability, mirroring

Why would MSFT would deprecate mirroring from 2012.. I understand alwaysON will replace it but then SE users are left with nothing..no alwaysON or dbm from future releases.. Just analyzing from end users POV.

Answer (score 4):

There is a difference between - [Features not supported in NEXT version of sql server](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143729(v=sql.110).aspx) vs [features not supported in a FUTURE version of sql server](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143729(v=sql.110).aspx).

Mirroring is [still available in SQL Server 2012, 2014 and 2016.](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143729(v=sql.130).aspx) It has been put into the future deprecated list, but as of now, it is still available.

AlwaysON (as it was with mirroring when it was first introduced in sql server 2005) is an enterprise feature and in sql server 2016 (CTP2.1) it [supports upto 2 nodes](http://www.brentozar.com/archive/2015/06/how-to-set-up-standard-edition-alwayson-availability-groups-in-sql-server-2016/) in standard edition as well.

Answer (score 2):

SQL Server 2016 introduces [Standard Edition support for AlwaysOn Availability Groups](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645993.aspx#High_availability).

It supports 2 nodes only, but as a replacement for mirroring that should be no problem.

Comment: [How to Set Up Standard Edition AlwaysOn Availability Groups in SQL Server 2016](http://www.brentozar.com/archive/2015/06/how-to-set-up-standard-edition-alwayson-availability-groups-in-sql-server-2016/)